Div design wont center
I try to center this code, but I can't find what in the code makes it placed on the left instead of centered.
I have changed the flex-direction to column instead of row as I had originally. Which did not give the desired result.


<div style="margin-top:3rem; margin-bottom:3rem;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: column; gap:0; justify-content: center; align-items: middle; margin:0 auto; width:100%;">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 30px; min-width: 369px; background-color: black; width:44%;">
      <p style="text-align:center; margin:0; color:white; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Book', sans-serif; letter-spacing:2px; font-size:16px; margin-bottom:0.25rem;"><a href="#saljarinfo">Se säljarinfo</a></p>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 580px; min-width: 369px; background-color: white; width:44%;">
      <?php if ($isHex): ?>
      <iframe id="frame" scrolling="yes" src="https://web.sendify.se/tracking/<?= isset($_GET['t']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['t']) : '' ?>" style="border: 0px none; height: 680px; margin-top: -100px; width:100%;">
                </iframe>
      <?php else: ?>
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height:100%; width:100%;">
        <h2 style=" font-family: 'Neue Montreal Medium' , sans-serif; font-size:36px; text-align:center; padding:4rem;">
          <?= $felmeddelande ?? "Inget femeddelande har angivits." ?>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 44%; min-width:369px; background-color:black; height: 580px; padding: 8px 0px; text-align:center;">
      <h2 style="color:white; font-size:28px; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Medium', sans-serif; font-weight:500; margin:0; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:0.5rem;">
        <a name="saljarinfo"></a>SÄLJARINFO</h2>
      <img src="<?= $bild ?? " " ?>" alt="Bild på säljaren!" style="width:180px; display:block; margin: 0 auto; border-radius:5px;">

      <h3 style="color:white; font-size:22px; margin:0; margin-top:0.5rem; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Book', sans-serif;">
        <?= $saljarNamn ?? "" ?>
      </h3>
      <p style="text-align:center; margin:0; color:white; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Thin', sans-serif; letter-spacing:4px; font-size:16px;">
        <?= $roll ?? "" ?>
      </p>

      <div style='height:1px; background-color:white; margin-top: 1.5rem; margin-bottom: 1.5rem; '></div>
      <p style="text-align:center; margin:0; color:white; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Book', sans-serif; letter-spacing:2px; font-size:16px; margin-bottom:0.25rem;">Tack för din order!</p>
      <p style="text-align:center; margin:0; color:white; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Book', sans-serif; letter-spacing:2px; font-size:16px; margin-bottom:1.25rem;">Jag är med Er hela vägen - Från idé till färdigt projekt!</p>
      <p style="text-align:center; margin:0; color:white; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Book', sans-serif; letter-spacing:2px; font-size:16px; margin-bottom:0.75rem;">Behöver du komma i kontakt med mig?</p>

      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: middle; flex-wrap: wrap; gap:1.5rem;">

        <a class="customClassHoverOverA" href="tel:<?= $telefon ?? " " ?>" title="Ring mig på <?= $telefon ?? " " ?>!"><i style="color:white; font-size:1.5rem;" class='fas fa-phone-alt'></i></a>

        <a class="customClassHoverOverA" href="mailto:<?= $epost ?? " " ?>" title="Skicka e-post till mig på <?= $epost ?? " " ?>!"><i style="color:white; font-size:1.5rem;" class='fas fa-mail-bulk'></i></a>

        <a class="customClassHoverOverA" href="<?= $id_kort ?? " " ?>" title="Mitt visitkort på <?= $id_kort ?? " " ?>!"><i style="color:white; font-size:1.5rem;" class='fas fa-id-card'></i></a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




Are you required to use inline styles? If not, CSS is really worth looking into.

It looks like you want the code to be centralized to parent element or web page.
I've added another div which will be a parent element, of your web page where you inserting this code.
Then for div (parent element), I've added the CSS #parent to centralized the div (inner element).
You are using display: flex; in the second div, which I've replaced with the display: table-caption; for center alignment.
Let me know in the comments, if this is working for you.


#parent {
  width:auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #parent div {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 748px) {
  #parent div {
    width: 54%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 644px) {
  #parent div {
    width: 64%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  #parent div {
    width: 72%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 524px) {
  #parent div {
    width: 78%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 464px) {
  #parent div {
    width: 86%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 434px) {
  #parent div {
    width: 92%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  #parent div {
    width: 94%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 408px) {
  #parent div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 398px) {
  #parent div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
<div id="parent">
<div style="margin-top:3rem; margin-bottom:3rem;">
    <div style="display: table-caption; gap:0; justify-content: center; align-items: middle; margin:0 auto; width:100%;">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 30px; min-width: 369px; background-color: black; width:44%;">
        <p style="text-align:center; margin:0; color:white; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Book', sans-serif; letter-spacing:2px; font-size:16px; margin-bottom:0.25rem;"><a href="#saljarinfo">Se säljarinfo</a></p>
</div>
        <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 580px; min-width: 369px; background-color: white; width:44%;">
            <?php if ($isHex): ?>
                <iframe id="frame" scrolling="yes" src="https://web.sendify.se/tracking/<?= isset($_GET['t']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['t']) : '' ?>"
                    style="border: 0px none; height: 680px; margin-top: -100px; width:100%;">
                </iframe>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height:100%; width:100%;">
                    <h2 style=" font-family: 'Neue Montreal Medium' , sans-serif; font-size:36px; text-align:center; padding:4rem;"><?= $felmeddelande ?? "Inget femeddelande har angivits." ?></h2>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 44%; min-width:369px; background-color:black; height: 580px; padding: 8px 0px; text-align:center;">
            <h2 style="color:white; font-size:28px; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Medium', sans-serif; font-weight:500; margin:0; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:0.5rem;"><a name="saljarinfo"></a>SÄLJARINFO</h2>
            <img src="<?= $bild ?? "" ?>" alt="Bild på säljaren!" style="width:180px; display:block; margin: 0 auto; border-radius:5px;">

            <h3 style="color:white; font-size:22px; margin:0; margin-top:0.5rem; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Book', sans-serif;"><?= $saljarNamn ?? "" ?></h3>
            <p style="text-align:center; margin:0; color:white; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Thin', sans-serif; letter-spacing:4px; font-size:16px;"><?= $roll ?? "" ?></p>

            <div style='height:1px; background-color:white; margin-top: 1.5rem; margin-bottom: 1.5rem; '></div>
            <p style="text-align:center; margin:0; color:white; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Book', sans-serif; letter-spacing:2px; font-size:16px; margin-bottom:0.25rem;">Tack för din order!</p>
            <p style="text-align:center; margin:0; color:white; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Book', sans-serif; letter-spacing:2px; font-size:16px; margin-bottom:1.25rem;">Jag är med Er hela vägen - Från idé till färdigt projekt!</p>
            <p style="text-align:center; margin:0; color:white; font-family: 'Neue Montreal Book', sans-serif; letter-spacing:2px; font-size:16px; margin-bottom:0.75rem;">Behöver du komma i kontakt med mig?</p>

            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: middle; flex-wrap: wrap; gap:1.5rem;">

                <a class="customClassHoverOverA" href="tel:<?= $telefon ?? "" ?>" title="Ring mig på <?= $telefon ?? "" ?>!"><i style="color:white; font-size:1.5rem;" class='fas fa-phone-alt'></i></a>

                <a class="customClassHoverOverA" href="mailto:<?= $epost ?? "" ?>" title="Skicka e-post till mig på <?= $epost ?? "" ?>!"><i style="color:white; font-size:1.5rem;" class='fas fa-mail-bulk'></i></a>

                <a class="customClassHoverOverA" href="<?= $id_kort ?? "" ?>" title="Mitt visitkort på <?= $id_kort ?? "" ?>!"><i style="color:white; font-size:1.5rem;" class='fas fa-id-card'></i></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>




It seems to work on the computer.
But when I try to view the page on the phone, it is still placed on the left.

I've added media query which will deal with smaller screens e.g. Phone.

The media query you added makes the content go left when the screen is smaller than 768px..

I've added another media query to handle that resolution.
